# Checkstyle - non deterministic check result

Tags: java, maven, runtime, checkstyle

I have a large JEE Maven Multi module project, and share a custom set of rules and suppressions for Checkstyle via build-tools module. I find very hard to release a stable version of this build-tools due to the testing of this same module.

Each time I run a Maven phase, I get a different execution result.

This is Checkstyle configuration in parent pom.xml:

```
<build>    
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${checkstyle.plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <skip>${skipQATests}</skip>
          <configLocation>qa/checkstyle_rules.xml</configLocation>
          <propertiesLocation>${checkstyleDir}/checkstyle.properties</propertiesLocation>
          <suppressionsLocation>qa/suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
          <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
          <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
          <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
             <id>checkstyle-compile</id>
             <phase>compile</phase>                     
             <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
             </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I'm trying to find a pattern in the executions, project is set to fail in one particular check and I cannot find the 'bug'.

1. I execute compile maven phase (mvn clean compile) and it fails on the given check.
2. I execute package maven phase (mvn clean package) and it fails too.
3. I execute again compile phase (mvn clean compile) and it doesn't fail (all SUCCESS)
4. I execute again package and it fails
5. It does not fail for a couple of runs and then it fails again on some different execution

I know this behavior is kind of difficult to trace without all project information. But is there any kind of procedure, log, tool that would give more information on debuging this problem so that I can determine if it's a bug or some mis-configuration??

Thanks in advance!!

**UPDATE:**

I have just executed the same mvn command twice on the sub-module I'm testing Checkstyle (test that forces a rule violation) - `mvn checkstyle:check -X`

Result was different from each other, the main differences are that the CORRECT EXECUTION (the one that fails the build does not find the files at the first try) and the WRONG EXECUTION (the one that ends in SUCCESS finds the configuration files at the first attempt)

**EXEC_1:** ...

```
[DEBUG] The resource 'qa/suppressions.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader.    
[DEBUG] The resource 'qa/suppressions.xml' was found as jar:file:/C:/Users/usuario/.m2/repository/com/company/tools/build-tools/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/build-tools-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/qa/suppressions.xml.    
[DEBUG] Adding the outputDirectory file:/C:/LAB/PRJ/prj-ejbws/target/classes/ to the Checkstyle class path    
[DEBUG] The resource 'qa/checkstyle_N4_JEE.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader.    
[DEBUG] The resource 'qa/checkstyle_N4_JEE.xml' was found as jar:file:/C:/Users/usuario/.m2/repository/com/company/tools/build-tools/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/build-tools-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/qa/checkstyle_JEE.xml.    
[DEBUG] The resource 'ubic.properties' was found as C:\LAB\PRJ\ubic.properties.

[INFO] Starting audit...    
[INFO] --------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.542s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 20 16:35:22 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] --------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:2.11:check (default-cli) on project GestionDelContacto-opsa-ejbws: Failed during checkstyle execution: There are 2 checkstyle errors.
```

**EXEC_2:**...

```
[DEBUG] The resource 'qa/suppressions.xml' was found as jar:file:/C:/Users/usuario/.m2/repository/com/company/tools/build-tools/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/build-tools-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/qa/suppressions.xml.    
[DEBUG] Adding the outputDirectory file:/C:/LAB/PRJ/prj-ejbws/target/classes/ to the Checkstyle class path    
[DEBUG] The resource 'qa/checkstyle_N4_JEE.xml' was found as jar:file:/C:/Users/usuario/.m2/repository/com/company/tools/build-tools/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/build-tools-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/qa/checkstyle_JEE.xml.    
[DEBUG] The resource 'ubic.properties' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.ThreadContextClasspathResourceLoader.    
[DEBUG] The resource 'ubic.properties' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.JarResourceLoader.    
[DEBUG] The resource 'ubic.properties' was found as C:\LAB\PRJ\ubic.properties.

[INFO] Starting audit...

[INFO] --------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] --------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.570s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 20 16:37:05 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] ---------------------------------------------
```

any clue?

Comment: What means fail? Do you get an error message?
Have you tried to run maven with -X -e options to get a more verbose output?

Comment: When I say fail I mean: Checkstyle detects the rule violation and breaks the build.
I have been studying this problem through all morning and have found the following:
- Plexus resource loader is the one that on some mvn executions does not load the properties file for checkstyle using propertiesLocation tag on plugin configuration, so when checkstyle is launched it does not have the properties loaded to make the propertyExpansion on my illegalImports Check.

Comment: Have you tried out fixed values for the location path instead of variables in your POM? You should also check, if the variables are set properly in you project. Especially multi-module-projects tend to run into problems if variables are inherited between subprojects.

Comment: I changed the value to fixed, but no change. It keeps the mentioned behavior. Sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't. -X execution returns this log for the files I'm loading (config, suppressions, properties)

`[DEBUG] The resource 'ubicacion.properties' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.URLResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] The resource 'ubicacion.properties' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.ThreadContextClasspathResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] The resource 'ubicacion.properties' was found as C:\LAB\PRJ\ubicacion.properties.`

Comment: Still no luck. I'm having the same problem and I'm unable to locate the bug...

Answer (score 0):

Stop using Maven, run CheckStyle separately. You already have sufficient "clues": sometimes Maven initializes CheckStyle correctly, sometimes not, and depending on unreliable infrastructure is a bad idea.